# How to REGEX replace with numbers - like $1<number>

Tags: regex, powershell

Let's assume I have a string "something" and want to get "some123".

This would be my regex: `/(some)(thing)/`

```
// Pseudocode
$something = 'something'
$someone = $something.replace(/(some)(thing)/, '$1one') ###works
$some123 = $something.replace(/(some)(thing)/, '$1123') ###fails
```

$someone will work without any problems, but $some123 will fail, as the interpreter will look for group 1123, which does not exist.

Any ideas? Thank you!

*(edit: I am using Powershell, but I think it's the same problem in other languages, like PHP, too)*

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Comment: `$1` is the first group (regex engine knows that in `$1one`). But `$11` is the 11 group, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's language independent - I am using this in Powershell. But I think the problem would be the same in PHP?

Comment: Using JS `$something.replace(/(some)(thing)/, '$1123')` gives me `some123`

Comment: @anubhava how does it know to separate `1` from `123`?

Comment: No, there is a difference. In JavaScript, [you would not have troubles at all](https://jsfiddle.net/zvcqtejj/). See Maroun Maroun's comment: the regex expects an 11th group that does not exist in the pattern.

Comment: Because JS sees there is no `$11` as it supports only `$1` to `$9` as back-reference

Comment: Working fine in JS console (Chrome 48). Could you provide further details?

Comment: You are right, it works perfectly in Javascript - but not for Powershell. I will tag my question with "powershell".

Comment: Looks like Powershell supports $XX back-references, hence it fails to find the `11` group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a .NET regex used in Powershell, you need to use `{}` around the capture group ID inside a backreference to remove any ambiguities:

```
$something = 'something'
$someone = $something -replace "(some)(thing)", '${1}one' ### someone
$some123 = $something -replace "(some)(thing)", '${1}123' ### some123
```

[image]

If you are unsure, you can also rely on **named captures**:

```
$someone = $something -replace "(?<some>some)(?<thing>thing)", '${some}one'
```

[image]

Comment: Or maybe named captures.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Sure, anything that will remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @MarounMaroun What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: You may use named captures: `$someone = $something -replace "(?<some>some)(?<thing>thing)", '${some}one'`