# How do I replace just the captured groups?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/mK1hS6/2):

```
.*time\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}\s(am|pm)).*
```

I have a string like this:

```
there is some text and maybe some number or symbols time 12:32 am and there is some text
//                                                  ^^^^^
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

Now I need to replace that captured group with another time. Like these:

```
there is some text and maybe some number or symbols time 01:21 am and there is some text
```

or any other time ..! Actually my main pattern is this:

```
{anything}{time }{AnyDigit}{AnyDigit}{:}{AnyDigit}{AnyDigit }{am|pm }{anything}
```

---

Well, How can I do that? *(replace a dynamic time with captured group)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose the enclosing subpatterns into capturing groups and use backreferences to restore the captured values before and after a new time value:

```
'~(.*time\s+)(\d{2}:\d{2}\s[ap]m)(.*)~'
  ^    1    ^^        2         ^^ 3^
```

Replace with `${1}10:10 pm$3`. The `${1}` is an *unambiguous numbered backreference to Group 1 captured text*. It is necessary because the next character will most probably be a digit, and PHP always checks for the 2-digit backreference group if the `$` is followed with 2 digits. If it sees `$11`, and if it does not find it, an error will pop up (unlike in JavaScript).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK1hS6/3)

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rhexW0):

```
$re = '~(.*time\s+)(\d{2}:\d{2}\s[ap]m)(.*)~'; 
$str = "there is some text and maybe some number or symbols time 12:32 am and there is some text"; 
$new_time = "10:10 pm"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, '${1}' . $new_time . '$3', $str);
echo $result;
// => there is some text and maybe some number or symbols time 10:10 pm and there is some text
```

Comment: Glad to help. I also added an IDEONE demo (as usual, adding the whole code necessary to reproduce it on your end). **The `${1}` must be inside single quotes** in the replacement.

Comment: Ah ok tnx for demo .. btw I think you learned how to separate the number of group that other numbers yesterday .. `;-)`

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I am not sure what you mean to say, but let me agree - I learn every day :)

Comment: I meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435947/how-to-replace-with-numbers-like-1number/35436255#35436255) ... I was writing an answer under that question, but you wrote faster than me ... Anyway please stop answering all REGEX questions `:-P`, We also like to answer `;-)`

Comment: I was away from the computer for 6 hours. I will go to bed in some half an hour. You will have plenty of time :) Also, I knew about `${}` long before yesterday. I have known it for about 7 years.

Comment: Really ?! I felt a delay to answer that question .. I thought you searched before answering ..! Anyway ok, good for you...

Comment: The delay was due to the fact that I always test before posting. It took me time to open Powershell and insert some lines there.